# How to display a loading gif in this situation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a ASP.NET Web Forms page that does a good amount of processing in the page_load event.  Ideally I would display a loading gif to my user while the page is loading. Since all the processing is on page_load, the page's html never gets rendered and all the user sees is a blank page.

I tried/brainstormed a few ideas, none of which were successful.

- Moved processing to unload event.  This doesn't work because Request and Response objects are not available at this point.
- Called a page method via ajax.  This doesn't work because I cannot access a non-static variable.  The processing involves access to the page request and response.
- A staging page that contains only the loading gif and on page load (client-side) redirects to the page that does the processing.  I tried Method 1 from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33613/Loading-Message-when-Page-Loads) but the problem here is that the process itself contains a redirect.  In other words, I can't point it to page1.aspx (the page that does the processing) because page1.aspx ultimately redirects to page2.aspx.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just call the complete page using a JQuery $.get() and render the results to a div?

Comment: Make that the answer so I can mark it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested :

Couldn't you just call the complete page using a JQuery $.get() and render the results to a div?